# How to hide video player in android when video is paused?

Tags: android, video, youtube-api, android-videoview

I have a layout with video player and youtube player, first is for movie, second is for trailer and I want to show them in the same position (video container).

If I don't start the movie, I have a movie poster -> I watch youtube trailer -> back to movie poster, then all works fine.

If I start watching movie -> pause movie -> watch trailer, then the fragment from video player is in front of youtube player.

When app is in portrait view, youtube player is behind the video player and I can only hear the sound, when in landscape, then still youtube player is behind paused video frame (see image). How to hide video player?

[image: youtube trailer is playing but paused frame from movie is in front]

```
trailerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            videoPlayerContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            youtubePlayerContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (videoPlayerView.isPlaying()) {
                videoPlayerView.pause();
                videoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, onInitializedListener);
        }
    });
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_player_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/movie_player_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <app.view.VideoPlayer
            android:id="@+id/movie_player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/youtube_player_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <fragment android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:name="app.fragment.YouTubeFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you got any solution as getting same problem.